# Storm supervisor dying at deployment

Tags: java, connection, apache-storm, distributed-computing

I have a topology tested on a single local node that works perfect. Now, I've deployed it in a 3 machine cluster, 2 of them are supervisor, the topology submits, and then I have these errors on the logs of the 2 supervisors

```
2016-05-13 13:31:10.689 b.s.u.StormBoundedExponentialBackoffRetry [INFO] The baseSleepTimeMs [2000] the maxSleepTimeMs [60000] the maxRetries [5]
2016-05-13 13:31:20.784 b.s.event [ERROR] Error when processing event
java.lang.RuntimeException: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at backtype.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.retryNext(TBackoffConnect.java:59) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:51) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.reconnect(ThriftClient.java:103) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.security.auth.ThriftClient.<init>(ThriftClient.java:72) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.<init>(NimbusClient.java:74) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.utils.NimbusClient.getConfiguredClient(NimbusClient.java:37) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.utils.Utils.downloadFromMaster(Utils.java:361) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$fn__7720.invoke(supervisor.clj:581) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.MultiFn.invoke(MultiFn.java:241) ~[clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.daemon.supervisor$mk_synchronize_supervisor$this__7638.invoke(supervisor.clj:465) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__7258.invoke(event.clj:40) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: org.apache.thrift7.transport.TTransportException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:187) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin.connect(SimpleTransportPlugin.java:103) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:48) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    ... 11 more
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:350) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589) ~[?:1.8.0_91]
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at org.apache.thrift7.transport.TFramedTransport.open(TFramedTransport.java:81) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.security.auth.SimpleTransportPlugin.connect(SimpleTransportPlugin.java:103) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at backtype.storm.security.auth.TBackoffConnect.doConnectWithRetry(TBackoffConnect.java:48) ~[storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    ... 11 more
2016-05-13 13:31:20.807 b.s.util [ERROR] Halting process: ("Error when processing an event")
java.lang.RuntimeException: ("Error when processing an event")
    at backtype.storm.util$exit_process_BANG_.doInvoke(util.clj:336) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:423) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at backtype.storm.event$event_manager$fn__7258.invoke(event.clj:48) [storm-core-0.10.0.jar:0.10.0]
    at clojure.lang.AFn.run(AFn.java:22) [clojure-1.6.0.jar:?]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:1.8.0_91]
2016-05-13 13:31:20.814 b.s.d.supervisor [INFO] Shutting down supervisor 1550b88e-276e-4d3a-b438-4a9d41157f07
```

The topology works on local mode, the machines are connected and I see the supervisors a little time before they suddenly die, and I can't see what's happenning here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you ssh from each machine to each other without pass phrase?

Comment: Yes, and they're ont he Storm UI until I launch the topology, after that, they fall with these errors, desappearing from the Storm UI when I refres. They fail when i launch the topology. Thanks!

Comment: When submitting a topology, new worker JVM are started. Maybe the problem is with your worker configuration...

Comment: I have the /etc/hosts with the nimbus ip, the zookeeper ip and other worker ip, the same on nimubs and zookeeper side. Do I need anything else in the worker configuration? I distributed this following a tutorial, maybe there's something missing. Thanks

Comment: No idea... Sorry. Maybe try to turn on debug/trace log level to get more information.